# Error in request then using WSDL2APEX

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex, xml

Im facing an issue when I try to import my WSDL into Salesforce and generate APEX code from this one. When I add a targetnamespace to my second schema in the following file, which is required in Salesforce, I need to update the reference so that my request still has the valid format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wss="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wss:querySearch>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Car>
            <Reg_Number></Reg_Number>
         </Car>
      </wss:querySearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My current WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="WebServiceProvider" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" version="1.0">
      <xs:import />
      <xs:element name="querySearch" type="tns:querySearch" />
      <xs:complexType name="querySearch">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="Car" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="querySearchResponse" type="tns:querySearchResponse" />
      <xs:complexType name="querySearchResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="Car" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="Car" type="Car" />
      <xs:complexType name="Car">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Reg_Number" type="xs:string" />

        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearch">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:querySearch" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearchResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:querySearchResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:querySearch" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:querySearchResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebServiceProviderPortBinding" type="tns:WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <soap:operation soapAction="querySearch" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WebServiceProvider">
    <wsdl:port name="WebServiceProviderPort" binding="tns:WebServiceProviderPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="XXXXXXXX" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I alter my WSDL to the following (adding a targetnamespace and adding the "tns:" to the types):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="WebServiceProvider" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="Car" type="tns:Car"/>
      <xs:complexType name="Car">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Reg_Number" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="querySearch" type="tns:querySearch"/>
      <xs:complexType name="querySearch">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:Car"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="querySearchResponse" type="tns:querySearchResponse"/>
      <xs:complexType name="querySearchResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:Car"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearch">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:querySearch" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearchResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:querySearchResponse" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:querySearch"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:querySearchResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebServiceProviderPortBinding" type="tns:WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <soap:operation soapAction="querySearch"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WebServiceProvider">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:WebServiceProviderPortBinding" name="WebServiceProviderPort">
      <soap:address location="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

It goes through Salesforce but generates the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wss="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wss:querySearch>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wss:Car>
            <wss:Reg_Number>?</wss:Reg_Number>
         </wss:Car>
      </wss:querySearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It adds the "wss" prefix to the Car element and the input paramter in the request, which makes the request invalid. Can I solve this in some way by altering the namespaces or something like that? The wsdl is generated from Dell Boomi and hence a solution from there would be prefered but for now I am satisfied if I can alter the WSDL manually.

Ciao!

Comment: I assume you have modified the WSDL due to the unsupported xs:import in the original WSDL that was created from https://connect.boomi.com/ws/soap?wsdl. Are you able to provide the full unmodified WSDL with the soap:address removed? I have a [free tool](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) that adds improved support for creating Apex classes from a WSDL.

Comment: Related [Trying to solve the "Error: Failed to parse wsdl: schema:targetNamespace can not be null" error without making the request invalid.](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000ArDPIA0)

Comment: Daniel: Partly yes, I used the connect.boomi.com/ws/soap?wsdl=single to remove the imports etc. Later I put the types in the same namespace and solved the issue with empty namespace. But I was still facing reference issues and prefixes in the input paramters which made the request invalid. So I changed the elementFormDefault="qualified" to "unqualified" and I was able to make a valid request through SF. And the related thread is mine as well..